# Unity 4.6 (new UI): Button click with complex image

Tags: image, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, click

I have a Button (Canvas>Panel>Button) with a complex image (is not square), the issue here is that I want it to execute the on click event when i click on the IMAGE (excluding parts of the image with no opacity) but since the new UI doesn't work with colliders I can't achieve the same click behaviour that could be achieved with a polygon collider, and its feels completely wrong to click outside the button (image) where the alpha is cero (0) and still execute the click events..

I hope my problem is clear enough and someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, Unity should have an option to achieve this but at least this works perfectly: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/none-rectangle-shaped-button.263684/#post-1744521

Answer (score 0):

I found another (probably better) solution for this problem. I used a `Collider2D` (`PolygonCollider2D`) to define the clickable shape and then used this RaycastFilter:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent (typeof (RectTransform), typeof (Collider2D))]
public class Collider2DRaycastFilter : MonoBehaviour, ICanvasRaycastFilter 
{
    Collider2D myCollider;
    RectTransform rectTransform;

    void Awake () 
    {
        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

#region ICanvasRaycastFilter implementation
    public bool IsRaycastLocationValid (Vector2 screenPos, Camera eventCamera)
    {
        var worldPoint = Vector3.zero;
        var isInside = RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(
            rectTransform,
            screenPos,
            eventCamera,
            out worldPoint
        );
        if (isInside)
            isInside = myCollider.OverlapPoint(worldPoint);
        return isInside;
    }
#endregion
}
```

Using a collider for this is a bit hacky but the result is much simpler, probably faster and makes it much easier to adjust the clickable shape.

This could be improved by creating a custom alternative to replace the `Collider2D` but that's a bit too much work for what I need.